# Exponential power series - why is the limit like that?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am looking at the exponential power series.

I have to calculate this:
$$R=\frac{1}{{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }} \sup \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}}.$$

But why is it like that:

$$\sqrt[n]{n!} \to +\infty?$$

I thought that it would be $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(n!)^{0}=1$.

Why isn't it like that?

Answer (score 1):

One way of seeing it is to consider $\log ((n!)^{\frac{1}{n}})$ and then use Stirling approximation for $n!$, so you get $\log n -1 +o(1)$, which of course diverges, hence the original expression $(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ diverges too.

EDIT: another way of seeing it is once again to consider the log and then do the following:
$$
\log(n!)^\frac{1}{n}=\frac{ \log n!}{n} =  \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k}{n} \sim \frac{n \log n}{n} = \log n
$$
Now exponentiate back and you can see the series diverges.

Comment: Isn't there also an other way,expect from using the Stirling approximation?

Comment: Do you mean 'besides Stirling approximation'? Of course, Stirling is the easiest.

Comment: What would be an other way?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on why you want to know this. You didn't specify there are restrictions on what approaches you are allowed to use.

Comment: OK, see the edit

Answer (score 1):

The calculation $\lim_n (n!)^{1/n} = (n!)^0 = 1$ is flawed because you cant take the limit only in the exponent but not in the base!

That would be like calculating $\lim_n 1 = \lim_n \frac{n^{-1}}{n^{-1}} = \frac{0}{n^{-1}} = 0$ which is also wrong.

Showing $\sqrt[n]{n!} \rightarrow \infty$ is not that straightforward; it is more easy in this case to show by different means (e.g. ratio test) that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges and then to conclude that $\limsup_n \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} = 0$.

Comment: But...calculating the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}$,don't we do it like that: $n^{\frac{1}{n}} \to n^0=1$ ? Or am I wrong??

If I show that the series converges ,that would mean that $\frac{x^n}{n!} \to 0$,how can I conclude then that $\frac{1}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \to 0$ ?

Comment: No, $n^{1/n} = \exp(\ln(n) \cdot 1/n)$. You can then use e.g. L'Hospital to conclude $\ln(n)/n \rightarrow 0$ which implies $n^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ together with continuity of $\exp$. There are of course other ways, but yours is not sound. For the other question; it follows because the formula for the convergence radius is $\frac{1}{\limsup_n \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}}$ and you have shown (by other means) that the radius of convergence is infinite.